# Ajax readyState== 3 is missing in IE8 browser sporadically

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the `Ajax` `request` to fetch the data and printing the each `readyState`. I see that, sporadically `readyState==3` is not coming and directly it is going to `readyState==4`.

I want to know in which case `Ajax` does not print the `readyState==3`?

I simple `java script` Ajax call no `JQuery`.

Comment: Maybe for cached requests? IE seems to cache a lot more than other browsers, so I would think it doesn't need to "load" anything (what `readyState` 3 means)

Comment: readyState==3 -> Interactive - Downloading, responseText holds the partial data.

Comment: Yes, and? If IE caches the request, it doesn't have to download anything - it just gets the response from its cache, so it skips step 3. I'm not 100% of this, but that's what I'm thinking.